# partial matching of character strings in R

Tags: r, variables, match

I want to make new column of car type from car full name.

From like this car full name of many manufacturers and cars. First word is campany name, and car type is next or not rightly next.

```
y = c("Volkswagan The Newbeatle", "Cadilac CTS", "Cadilac CTS-V",....)
```

I have car type vector, actually by each company. This is just example.

```
x = c("SLR", "Newbeatle", "300C", "CTS-V", "Spider", "CTS", ...)
```

The goal is return car type by matching with car full name vector.

```
result = c("Newbeatle", "CTS", "CTS-V", ...)

length(result)==length(y)
## TRUE
```

I already get the result. but professor ask me to don't use "for" and "if".

This is my R code(for example).

```
library(tidyverse)

# This is cartype
x <- c("abc", "def", "xyz", "lmn")
# This is car full name
y <- c("abc xxx", "lmn xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xyz xxxx x x", "xxx xxx", "def xxx") 
# Split car name by blank(" ")
ys <- str_split(y, " ", simplify = T) 

# I want to new colume.
result <- NULL

for(i in 1:length(ys)){
  for(j in 1:length(x)){
    if(length(grep(x[j], ys[i]))>0){
      result[i]=x[j]
    }
  }
}

> result
[1] "abc" "lmn" NA    "xyz" NA    "def"
```

This is work but show warning and professor not reccomend use looping function "for" and "if" for this goal.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
x <- c("abc", "def", "xyz", "lmn")
y <- c("abc xxx", "lmn xxx", "xxx xxx xxx", "xyz xxxx x x", "xxx xxx", "def xxx") 
ys <- str_split(y, " ", simplify = T) 
unlist(lapply(ys, function(l){x[l == x]}))
```